# Include results without an address when using ruby Geocoder

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the Geocoder gem in my RoR app to search a database of objects that may or may not have a address. When a user searches for these objects using a location, I want to show them both objects with an address near the location as well as objects that do not have an address. Currently I have something like this:

```
@objects = Object.near(location, 50)
```

This only returns objects within a 50 mile radius of `location`. Is there a way to include objects with `address == nil` in a single query?

Comment: You can try `Object.near(location, 50).or(Object.where(location: nil))` for newer Rails apps. Or try the [active_record_union](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union) gem

Comment: Neither of those methods seam to work. With `or` I'm getting an error about the relation having incompatible structure and with `union` I'm getting an error about the queries not having the same number of columns.

Comment: Records returned from the Geocoding query will have extra fields (distance, bearing, maybe some others I can't remember). If you look at the SQL query you'll see it adds these to the 'SELECT' statement. You can pass in options to #near to remove these selects. Try something like Object.near(location,50, {select_distance: false, select_bearing: false}). Although, thinking about it, you most likely want the distances in the results. I would suggest two separate queries. If the lat/long fields are indexed (and they should be), finding those that are nil will not take long

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I'll need the distances for now so this should get me what I need.